# How can I reversibly compress a ciphertext?

Tags: encryption, rust, cryptography

I am a Rust developer and I want to know how I can do the following:

Let's say, for example, I have a ciphertext (not a real one):

`ddofjasf9dasdf=-6yoadfhasfh8adfsdfzsdfjnzsfh8adfsdfzsdfjnzf9dasdf=-fhasfh8adfsdfzsdfjnzsfh8adfsdfzsdfjnzf9dasdf6yoadfhaasf9dasdf=-p-dfhasfh8adfsdfzsdfjnzsfh8adfsdfzsdfjnzf9dasdf=-jasf9da`.

How can I compress this in a way like a SHA256 hash and then convert it back to its original state? The reason I want to do this is that the ciphertexts I'm generating are pretty big and I want to reduce the size as much as possible.

Comment: Ciphertext are randomized by definition (your one is not really randomized, which probably shows that it was humanly generated). So it doesn't compress very well, if at all. You can compress the plaintext message obviously, but you **should** make sure that you don't leak any information through the ciphertext size if you do. A hash is a cryptographic algorithm, it does perform compression but that type of compression is not reversible.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about programming in itself, Rust doesn't have anything to do with the question.

Comment: CRIME and BREACH are a couple of well-known attacks where compression undermined the privacy of encrypted channels. It's difficult to get this right, even for experts.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I specified Rust so if you were to recommend anything to me, it would be a crate. Absolutely pathetic reason to close a question.

Comment: There have been multiple sites defined for a reason. Why not first get your first question answered on how you would compress ciphertext, then check if you can implement it *if required* ask for help with Rust once you get stuck? Otherwise we end up with questions on how to compress ciphertext for Rust, Java, C++, JavaScript etc. etc. while the answer simply remains the same.

Comment: *"I specified Rust so if you were to recommend anything to me, it would be a crate."* -- questions simply looking for library recommendations (eg, crates) are off topic, and in order for your question to be valid as a programming question you would need a specific question where you were trying to implemt something yourself and a [mcve] showing what you have tried and how it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I compress this in a way like a SHA256 hash and then convert it back to its original state?

You can't. A hash is not a compression. It is irreversible. Compression is things like [deflate](https://crates.io/crates/deflate) instead.

Also, encrypted data are mostly like random in that they cannot be really compressed, if anything you would need to compress before doing the encryption.